# Parsing JSON response from James Mallison twitter library

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am using the Twitter Search API 1.1 to search followers_count

I have managed to get the Oauth working with the help of James Mallison at http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php.

Here my code :

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "yyy",
'consumer_key' => "zzz",
'consumer_secret' => "vvv"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=twitterapi';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest();


$response = json_decode($twitter, true);
$ed = $response->followers_count;
```

Here the answer :

```
[{"id":6253282,"id_str":"6253282","name":"Twitter API","screen_name":"twitterapi","location":"San Francisco, CA","description":"The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/78pYTvWfJd","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/78pYTvWfJd","expanded_url":"http:\/\/dev.twitter.com","display_url":"dev.twitter.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":3402865,"friends_count":48,"listed_count":12958,"created_at":"Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007","favourites_count":27,"utc_offset":-25200,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":3535,"lang":"en","status":{"created_at":"Thu May 21 21:12:42 +0000 2015","id":601495856353783808,"id_str":"601495856353783808","text":"RT @TwitterDev: We are excited to announce that the REST API now supports native video upload. https:\/\/t.co\/cWUrgjh8wz http:\/\/t.co\/yaenTQE9\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu May 21 20:57:40 +0000 2015","id":601492072953151488,"id_str":"601492072953151488","text":"We are excited to announce that the REST API now supports native video upload. https:\/\/t.co\/cWUrgjh8wz http:\/\/t.co\/yaenTQE95N","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/jonbulava.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eJon's Developer Testing App\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":160,"favorite_count":189,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/cWUrgjh8wz","expanded_url":"https:\/\/blog.twitter.com\/2015\/rest-api-now-supports-native-video-upload","display_url":"blog.twitter.com\/2015\/rest-api-\u2026","indices":[79,102]}],"media":[{"id":601491637433475073,"id_str":"601491637433475073","indices":[103,125],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/601491637433475073\/pu\/img\/XJcHkzdOR2YRMQSC.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/601491637433475073\/pu\/img\/XJcHkzdOR2YRMQSC.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/yaenTQE95N","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/yaenTQE95N","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/TwitterDev\/status\/601492072953151488\/video\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":640,"h":360,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"retweet_count":160,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"TwitterDev","name":"TwitterDev","id":2244994945,"id_str":"2244994945","indices":[3,14]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/cWUrgjh8wz","expanded_url":"https:\/\/blog.twitter.com\/2015\/rest-api-now-supports-native-video-upload","display_url":"blog.twitter.com\/2015\/rest-api-\u2026","indices":[95,118]}],"media":[{"id":601491637433475073,"id_str":"601491637433475073","indices":[119,140],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/601491637433475073\/pu\/img\/XJcHkzdOR2YRMQSC.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/ext_tw_video_thumb\/601491637433475073\/pu\/img\/XJcHkzdOR2YRMQSC.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/yaenTQE95N","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/yaenTQE95N","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/TwitterDev\/status\/601492072953151488\/video\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":340,"h":191,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":640,"h":360,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":337,"resize":"fit"}},"source_status_id":601492072953151488,"source_status_id_str":"601492072953151488","source_user_id":2244994945,"source_user_id_str":"2244994945"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"lang":"en"},"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/656927849\/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/656927849\/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174872\/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174872\/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/6253282\/1431474710","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false}]

Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in ...
```

I don't kwnow why i can't use json_decode

Any feedback or ideas on how to reach followers_count correctly would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
$jsonResponse = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest();

$data = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
$ed = $data[0]['followers_count'];
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) `json_decode` documentation.

Comment: Thank for the answer @Leggendario but when i print the $ed variable it's empty.

Comment: `var_dump($data);` returns `null`?

Comment: Excuse me @Leggendario It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time. Stackoverflow's members rocks...